# totalprice is not called

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="banner">
        <div class="navbar"> 
            <img src="logo.png" class="logo">   
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="order.php">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Vinyl Floor (SQFT)</h1>

<form action="checkout.php" method="post" >
<div class="box">
    <div class="input-container">
        <label for="length">Total Length in Feet:</label>
        <input type="number" id="length"><br><br>
        <label for="width">Total Width in Feet:</label>
        <input type="number" id="width" onkeydown="checkTab(event)">
    </div>

   
&nbsp;

        <div class="result">
        
            <label for="totalSQFT">Total SQFT:</label>
            <input name="totalSQFT" type="text" id="totalSQFT" readonly>

            <label for="vinyl">Vinyl (pcs):</label>
            <input name="vinyl" type="text" id="vinyl" readonly>
  
            <label for="vinylBox">Vinyl (box):</label>
            <input name="vinylBox" type="text" id="vinylBox" readonly>

            <label for="skirting">Skirting (pcs):</label>
            <input name="skirting" type="text" id="skirting" readonly>
     
            <label for="installation">Installation RM:</label>
            <input name="installation" type="text" id="installation" readonly>
            
         <input type="hidden" name="vinylTotal" id="vinylTotal" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="skirtingTotal" id="skirtingTotalInput" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" id="totalPriceInput" value="">
        </div>  </form>
```

This is how send the data using the form.php. And the way i pass around the data is by using the hidden input.

```
function calculateValues() {
  // Get values from input boxes
  const length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("length").value) || 0;
  const width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value) || 0;

  const totalSQFT = length * width;

  const vinyl = Math.round(totalSQFT / 1.5);
  const vinylBox = Math.max(1, Math.round(totalSQFT / 1.5 / 15));

  const skirting = Math.ceil((length + width) * 2 / 8);
  const skirtingPrice = 11.50;
  const skirtingTotal = (skirtingPrice * skirting).toFixed(2);


  const installation = (totalSQFT * 3).toFixed(2);
  const vinylPrice = 96.30;
  const vinylTotal = vinylBox * vinylPrice;

  const totalPrice = vinylTotal + parseFloat(skirtingTotal) + parseFloat(installation);


  document.getElementById("totalPriceInput").value = totalPrice;
  document.getElementById("skirtingTotalInput").value = skirtingTotal;
  document.getElementById("vinylTotal").value = vinylTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("totalSQFT").value = totalSQFT.toFixed(2); // Keep two decimal places
  document.getElementById("vinyl").value = vinyl;
  document.getElementById("vinylBox").value = vinylBox;
  document.getElementById("skirting").value = skirting;
  document.getElementById("installation").value = installation;

}
```

```
                        <tr class="total">
                            <td>Total  </td>
                            <td class="price" id="totalPrice"><?php echo $_POST['totalPrice']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```

I do try check whether the data is sent or not, and what i get is the data is send,but only totalPrice is not send/retrieve correctly. the method that i use to retrieve and post the data for vinyl,skirting is same as totalPrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this issue arising bacause you're trying to access the `totalPrice` in your PHP code. When you submit the form using the `POST` method, you should use the `$_POST` superglobal to access the form data. However, in your PHP code, it looks like you are trying to access `$_POST['totalPrice']` directly, but the input field name is `totalPriceInput`.

Please modify the code as follows.

```
<tr class="total">
    <td>Total  </td>
    <td class="price" id="totalPrice"><?php echo $_POST['totalPriceInput']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Make sure to change `$_POST['totalPrice']` to `$_POST['totalPriceInput']` in your PHP code, and it should retrieve the correct value sent from the form.

Please let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks @SammaDev, your solution works  think this is because the mismatch of the name of my id. You really help me thank you 